# 2D Polygon in 3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, geometry, polygons

What is the easiest way to implement a polygon in a `Graphics3D`? I want to take a regular polygon, the hexagon for example, and be able to easily rotate it in 3D, as well as set its distance to the origin (relative to its centroid), as sketched below

[image]

for some $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $r$. Any ideas?

**My attempt:** I started by using `RegularPolygon` as follows

```
hex = Append[#, 0] & /@ CanonicalizePolygon[RegularPolygon[6]][[1]];
Graphics3D[{Yellow, Polygon@hex}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
```

but already I get a problem:

[image]

where do I go from here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at the [`TranslationTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TranslationTransform.html) and [`RotationTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html)

```
With[
    {coord=TranslationTransform[{1,0,0}][Append[0]/@CirclePoints[7]]},
    Animate[
        Graphics3D[
            {
                Blue, Arrow[{{0,0,0},{1,0,0}}],
                Red, 
                Polygon[RotationTransform[a,{1,0,0}][coord]]
            }
            , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
            , Axes->True
            , PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2},{-2,2}}
        ]
        ,{a,0,2Pi,Pi/20}
    ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: I tend to use `PadRight[CirclePoints[7], {Automatic, 3}]` instead of `Append[0] /@ CirclePoints[7]`, but this is otherwise how I'd do it.

Answer (score 7):

- **Use `SphericalCoordinates`**

In the affine transform `GeometricTransformation[g, {m, v}]`,we set `m=RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}` and `v=center`.

```
With[{vector = FromSphericalCoordinates[{r, θ, φ}]}, 
 Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], FaceForm[Yellow], 
     EdgeForm[{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]}], 
     GeometricTransformation[
      RegionProduct[RegularPolygon[{1,0},6], 
       Point[{0}]], {RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, vector}], 
       vector}]}, {Red, Sphere[vector, .05]}, 
    Arrow[{{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
        0}, {0, 0, 3}}}], Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, vector}]}, 
   Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> 3.5], {{r, 2}, 
   1, 3}, {{θ, π/6}, 0, π-.1}, {{φ, π/3}, 0,
    2 π}]]
```

Or

```
With[{vector = FromSphericalCoordinates[{r, θ, φ}]},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], FaceForm[Yellow], 
     EdgeForm[{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]}], 
     Polygon[TranslationTransform[
        vector]@(CirclePoints[{1.2, 0}, 6] . 
         Most@Orthogonalize@Normal@HodgeDual@vector)]}, {Red, 
     Sphere[vector, .03]}, {Arrow[{{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
         0}, {0, 3, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}}], Red, 
     Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, vector}]}}, Boxed -> False, 
   ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, PlotRange -> 3.5], {{r, 2}, 1, 
   3}, {{θ, π/6}, 0, π - .1}, {{φ, π/3}, 
   0, 2 π}]]
```

[image]

**Edit-2**

```
normal = {1, 2, 3};
center = {-2.5, .2, 2.5};
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], FaceForm[Yellow], 
   EdgeForm[{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]}], 
   Polygon[TranslationTransform[
      center]@(CirclePoints[{1.2, 0}, 6] . 
       Most@Orthogonalize@Normal@HodgeDual@normal)]}, {Red, 
   Sphere[center, .03]}, {Arrow[{{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
       0}, {0, 3, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 3}}}], Red, 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, center}]}}, Boxed -> False, 
 ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

Or

```
normal = {1, 2, 3};
center = {-2.5, .2, 2.5}; 
Graphics3D[{{Opacity[.5], FaceForm[Yellow], 
   EdgeForm[{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]}], 
   GeometricTransformation[
    RegionProduct[RegularPolygon[6], 
     Point[{0}]], {RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}], 
     center}]}, {Red, Sphere[center, .05]}, 
  Arrow[{{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 0, 3}}}], Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, center}]}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image]

**Edit-1**

```
CirclePoints[6] . Most@Orthogonalize@Normal@HodgeDual@{1, 1, 1} // 
  Polygon // Graphics3D
```

[image]

Or

```
RegionProduct[RegularPolygon[6], Point[{0}]] // Graphics3D
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to incorporate this in a 3D grid (with axes) so that I can include other polygons with different positions and angles?

Comment: @samwolfe  `normal = {1, 1, 1};
Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[
   RegionProduct[RegularPolygon[6], Point[{0}]], 
   RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, normal}]], Point[{0, 0, 0}], 
  Arrow[{{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, {{0, 0, 
      0}, {0, 0, 1}}}]}, Axes -> True]`?

Comment: @cvgmt is this the PostScript you're talking about? en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript

Comment: @hana Yes. But we are not easy to directly use PostScript for `Clip` and `UnFill`. I do this by use another drawing language which based on PostScript name asy https://asymptote.sourceforge.io/

Comment: @cvgmt thanks, then I probably have to try photoshop instead.